# what does shutil (in Python) mean?

Tags: terminology, shutil, mnemonics

I knew what this module is for, I just don't know why they choose this name - shutil. It is hard to remember this kind of "random" name if I don't know where it come from. Please give me some hints, thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It means "shell utilities", sh standing for shell, util standing for utilities.

If you think about what shutil does, that makes sense (manipulate the filesystem, make archives, etc.).

Comment: Maybe the module could have been named sh_utils to make it more clear.  @Rafe Good and clear explanation

Comment: @KornP that wouldn't fit with typical naming conventions for modules.

Comment: Well, yes and no. This is what I read in PEP8 regarding module names: "Modules should have short, all-lowercase names.  Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability." But it is not that important.

Comment: @KornP not so much based on PEP8 but based on the way that modules in the standard library are named. But yes, you are correct.